# SSL Handshake Exception in EC2 Machine

Tags: java, http, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I want to make connection to a site using normal HTTP Request:

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
public class SSLTest {
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
    SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
    URL url = new URL("https://www.1aauto.com/1961-64-chevy-bel-air-biscayne-impala-fuel-tank-with-strap-set/i/1afrk00087");
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
    conn.disconnect();
}
private static class DefaultTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Now, on my local, its working fine and giving 200 response. But on an AWS EC2 Instance, Its thowing an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:953)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
at SSLTest.main(SSLTest.java:24)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
... 9 more
```

What am missing in here. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your local and EC2 Java versions the same? `www.1aauto.com` [only supports TLS 1.2](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.1aauto.com) which is enabled by default in Java 1.8 but not in earlier versions.

[image: Protocols section of SSL Labs report showing only TLS 1.2 enabled]
[image: Handshake simulation section of SSL Labs report showing errors with older version of Java with default settings]

Also, `www.1aauto.com` presents a valid certificate trusted by the default Java truststore. Why exactly are you using neutered versions of TrustManager and HostnameVerifier? Using insecure code such as this in a Production environment is not recommended.